# DBGeography: Which namespace to use?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, geography

The namespaces system.data.spatial.dbgeography and system.data.entity.spatial.dbgeography appear to have the same methods and properties.

Which one should I use? That is, are there any advantages in using one and not the other?

Comment: im assuming the different namespaces have different functions, so i assume it would depend on what you need

Comment: https://cmatskas.com/working-with-dbgeography-points-and-polygons-in-net/  and https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/03/27/solving-spatial-types-and-functions-are-not-available-with-entity-framework/ will help you on this